# Имя файла относительно папки в bash shell

Tags: bash, unix, shell

Имеется папка структуры:

```
folder/
  file-1.txt
  file-2.txt
  file-3.doc
  nested-folder/
   file-4.txt
   file-5.doc
   file-6.doc
```

Нужно вывести в bash shell названия файлов относительно этой папки и только .txt.
Пример:

```
file-1.txt
file-2.txt
nested-folder/file-4.txt
```

У меня получился такой скрипт:

```
folder=(/path/to/folder/**/*.txt)

for ((i=0; i<${#folder[@]}; i++)); do
    echo ${folder[$i]}
done
```

Но он выводит полные пути, а именно:

```
/path/to/folder/file-1.txt 
/path/to/folder/file-2.txt 
/path/to/folder/nested-folder/file-4.txt
```

Как мне улучшить данный скрипт?

Comment: ```find dir -printf '%P\n' | grep .txt```

Comment: @karaname а можно пожалуйста поподробней куда это ставить в скрипте?

Comment: @karaname, +1. Можно find дополнить аргументами  `-type f -name \*.txt` и обойтись без 'grep'a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это очень просто:

```sh
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir -p f/n
$ touch f/f.txt f/f.doc f/n/f.txt f/n/f.doc
$ find f -name '*.txt'
f/f.txt
f/n/f.txt
```

Причём, работает даже в *POSIX Shell*.